# onSubmit updates comment list infinitely on Firebase

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

My firebase calls to update

```
const comment = doc(db, "Comments", "8-21-2022");

onSnapshot(comment, (doc) => {
    // get all existing comments
    let allComments = doc.data().Comments;
    
    // create a new comment
    let newComment = {
        Body: comment.value,
        Replies: [],
        Upvotes: 0
    }

    // add new comment 
    allComments.push(newComment);
    
    // convert comments to firebase object
    var transformedObject = {};
    transformedObject["Comments"]=allComments;

    // set 
    setDoc(comment, transformedObject);
})
```

My submit component I'm rendering

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input type="text" id="comment"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

What's going wrong with my code that it's infinitely adding the comment into the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onSnapshot` attaches a listener to the document that immediately gives you the current value of the document and that then continues listening for  updates to that document.

Inside the handler you then update the document, which triggers the `onSnapshot` listener again, which causes the endless loop.

---

The quick fix is to use `getDoc` instead of `onSnapshot`:

```
getDoc(comment).then((doc) => {
    // get all existing comments
    let allComments = doc.data().Comments;
    
    // create a new comment
    let newComment = {
        Body: comment.value,
        Replies: [],
        Upvotes: 0
    }

    // add new comment 
    allComments.push(newComment);
    
    // convert comments to firebase object
    var transformedObject = {};
    transformedObject["Comments"]=allComments;

    // set 
    setDoc(comment, transformedObject);
})
```

Also have a look at [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). Since the new value of the document depends on its current value, a transaction helps prevent multiple users from overwriting each other's changes.